# Degree of the curve in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let S be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g \ge2$, and $\iota_{K}:S\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ canonical mapping of $S$.

What is a definition of the degree of the curve $C =\iota_{K}(S)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, the degree of a curve $C\subset\Bbb P^N$ is given by $H\cdot C$, the number of points in which a generic hyperplane in $\Bbb P^N$ meets $C$. Since you're considering the canonical mapping $\iota_K$, the hyperplane section pulls back to the canonical divisor on $S$, which has degree $2g-2$. [One way to see this is to apply Riemann Roch to the canonical divisor itself: $h^0(K)-h^0(K-K) = d-g+1$, and, by definition, $h^0(K) = g$.]

(If $S$ is hyperelliptic, the canonical map factors through a branched two-fold cover of $\Bbb P^1$, and $\Bbb P^1$ maps to $\Bbb P^{g-1}$ as the rational normal curve, $[1,t]\rightsquigarrow [1,t,t^2,\dots,t^{g-1}]$. The rational normal curve, of course, has degree $g-1$, but the two-fold cover doubles the degree and we still get $2(g-1)=2g-2$.)

Comment: The degree in algebraic geometry is *not* the degree of a mapping in the sense of differential topology. If the algebraic curve $S$ is non-hyperelliptic, $\iota_K$ maps $S$ diffeomorphically to $C$ (so the mapping is degree $1$); the it is hyperelliptic, $\iota_K$ is a degree $2$ mapping (because it factors through a degree $2$ mapping to $\Bbb P^1$). But the degree of a divisor here is generalizing degree of a polynomial, not degree of a mapping (in differential topology or algebraic topology). It tells you how the curve $C$ is sitting inside $\Bbb P^{g-1}$, so it's extrinsic, not intrinsic.